# jquery - sorting li position when other li expand

Tags: javascript, jquery

wonder if anyone could help me on this:

when my animation expands the `<li>` to reveal the content, there are jumps and sometimes some places remain empty due to the floating of the `<li>` elements, it makes sense and it is correct but i was just wondering if i could somehow tell the `<li>`s to re-order in order to occupy all the available space if any.

```
(function ($) {
    // Get all menu items with IDs starting with "filter-" and loop over them
    $(".menu li[id|=filter]").each(function () {
        // Get the ID add extract the page class name from it (remove "filter-" from it)
        var type = $(this).attr("id").replace("filter-", "");
        // Get the items in the "webbies" list with that class name
        var items = $(".webbies li[class~=" + type + "]");
        // Don't do anything if there aren't any
        if (items.length == 0) return;
        // Get a list of the other items in the list
        var others = $(".webbies li:not([class~=" + type + "])");
        // Add a click event to the menu item
        $("a", this).click(function (e) {
            // Stop the link
            e.preventDefault();
            // Close open item
            if (openItem) {
                close(openItem);
            }
            items.removeClass("inactive").animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            others.addClass("inactive").animate({
                opacity: 0.2
            });
        });
    });
    var openItem;
    // Opens an item
    var open = function (item) {
            // Close open item
            if (openItem) close(openItem);
            $("img", item).first().hide("slow");
            item.animate({
                width: 350,
                height: 370
            });
            $("div.info", item).show("slow", function () {
                $("div.fader", item).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
            });
            // Set open item
            openItem = item;
        };
    // Closes an item
    var close = function (item) {
            $("div.fader", item).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, function () {
                $("div.info", item).hide("slow");
                item.animate({
                    width: 150,
                    height: 90
                });
                $("img", item).first().show("slow");
            });
            // Reset open item
            openItem = null;
        };
    $(".webbies li").each(function () {
        var item = $(this);
        $("div.fader", item).css("opacity", 0);
        $("a.showMe", item).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (item.hasClass("inactive")) return;
            open(item);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some html too :)

Comment: Argh now i understand. The way floats work, dosen't make them able to consider each other. So the only way is positioning them while comparing them. This plugin would do exactly that: http://masonry.desandro.com/ - for a more advanced plugin look at: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ - but masonry should be exactly what your looking for

Comment: ok, i will investigate into it! Thanks guys, actually didn't know about masonry, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to use masonry as linked by the previous comments, my final code is this:

```
     jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#container').masonry({
 itemSelector: '.box',
   columnWidth: 190,
animate: true
});
 });

(function ($) {
 // Get all menu items with IDs starting with "filter-" and loop over them
 $(".menu li[id|=filter]").each(function () {
// Get the ID add extract the page class name from it (remove "filter-" from it)
var type = $(this).attr("id").replace("filter-", "");
// Get the items in the "webbies" list with that class name
var items = $("#container div[class~=" + type + "]");
// Don't do anything if there aren't any
if (items.length == 0) return;
// Get a list of the other items in the list
var others = $("#container div:not([class~=" + type + "])");
// Add a click event to the menu item
$("a", this).click(function (e) {
    // Stop the link
    e.preventDefault();
    // Close open item
    if (openItem) {
        close(openItem);
    }
    items.removeClass("inactive").animate({opacity: 1});
    others.addClass("inactive").animate({opacity: 0.2});
});
  });

  var openItem;

  // Opens an item
 var open = function (item) {
// Close open item
if (openItem) close(openItem);
$("img", item).first().hide("slow");
item.width(340)
item.height(360);
$("div.fader", item).animate({opacity: 1}, function () {
    $("#container").masonry('reloadItems', function () {
        $("div.info", item).show("slow");

    });

});
// Set open item
openItem = item;

   };

 // Closes an item
  var close = function (item) {
$("div.fader", item).animate({opacity: 0});
$("div.info", item).hide("slow");
item.animate({width: 150, height: 100}, function () {
    $("img", item).first().show("slow");
    $("#container").masonry('reloadItems');
});

// Reset open item
openItem = null;
     };

 $("#container div.box").each(function () {
var item = $(this);
$("div.fader", item).css("opacity", 0);
$("a.showMe", item).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (item.hasClass("inactive")) return;
    open(item);
});
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I thought of was to use j[Query Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and recalculate after resizing with `.masonry( 'reloadItems' )`